# Does no zero divisors in quotient ring imply no zero divisors in original ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring and let $I$ be a proper ideal of $R$.

If $R/I$ has no zero divisors, then is it true that $R$ has no zero divisors?

My attempt:
Suppose $R$ has zero divisors, say $ab=0$ for some $a,b\in R^*$. Then $(a+I)(b+I)=ab+I=I$. However, I cannot exclude the case where $a,b\in I$.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hint: every nontrivial ring has a maximal ideal

Comment: So what when $I$ is not the maximal ideal? still confused...

Comment: When $I$ is a maximal ideal, what do we know about the quotient?

Comment: Then the quotient is a simple ring.

Comment: It is also a field, hence it has no zero divisors. We can thus take arbitrary ring with zero divisors, and create a quotient which has none.

Answer (score 4):

If you try to prove something and hit a wall, then you should switch to finding a counterexample for a while. Then if that doesn't work, try proving again. Back and forth you go.

Really you should find a counterexample right away. You could, for example, take a look at $\Bbb Z/\Bbb Z4$.

Answer (score 2):

No.
Z6/<2> is an integral domain as Z6 is a CRU and <2> is a prime ideal but Z6 is not a integral domain.